# Understanding JavaScript Runtime

Tags: javascript, dom

Consider following JavaScript object

```
var planet = {
    id: 1001,
    Name: "Mars",
    faction: {
        factionId: 2,
        notification: function () {
            document.write("Mars notified");
        }
    },
    cities: [
        { locationId: 15, name: "Gladius" },
        { city: "MyPlanet", geo: "universal" }
    ]
}
```

When trying to read `planet.cities` in Chrome Debugger windows I see these additional items.

[image]

Are these part of JavaScript Runtime engine, and do different browsers handle them differently ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every JavaScript has a prototype object from which it inherits ([EcmaScript §4.2.1](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.2.1)). This is usually referred to as the "internal `[[prototype]]` property" ([EcmaScript §8.6.2](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2)). That FF and Chrome make it public as the non-standard (and deprecated) [`__proto__` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) is implementation-specific.

These additional properties you see are on `Object.prototype` ([EcmaScript §15.2.4](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Object_instances)), from which all plain objects - and so your object literals - inherit. Again, the double-underscore-properties are implementation-specific and now deprecated by property descriptors (see [`Object.defineProperty` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Object_instances)).

Comment: @RobG: True, although there is no replacement for assigning to it